# Infiniband + Maas?

Tags: 12.04, server, maas, pxe

I'm looking at setting up an HPC based on Mellanox Infiniband rather than Ethernet.

Because I have many nodes to manage, I was looking at trying something new, like MAAS.

I know Infiniband cards support PXE through the FlexBoot system, but what other obstacles might I face?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I have exactly the same question...