# Ubuntu Server 16.04 cluster with infiniband?

Tags: maas, cluster

I have freshly installed Ubuntu Server 16.04 on a **Dell T3500** as the master node and I am planning to add 4 compute nodes to the cluster. There is one **ConnectX-2 HCA** (dual port) card in the T3500 and it is connected to a **Voltaire 4036** managed switch. The `ofed` package installed successfully (green and yellow LEDs switched ON) and I wonder if I can use `MAAS` to add the compute node via `infiniband`?
There is an old thread but there is no solution provided.
[Infiniband + Maas?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346780/infiniband-maas)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am getting back to this and I finally use IPoIB for port ib0 and assign static internal ip i.e. 192.168.8.X to ib0 of each node.
Installation of the MLNX-OFED on each node is necessary and I add ib_ipoib into /etc/modules so it is loaded every time the node boots.
I also added the ip of each node to /etc/hosts. After setting up the pass-wordless ssh, I can ssh to each node and it is now done.

But not via MAAS.

Thanks again.